# Ionic 3 - How to Upload a video file from gallery to Firebase storage

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, angularfire2, ionic-native

I have found many solutions for uploading images and audio to Firebase storage from Ionic 3 but not a single solution for uploading video file from gallery to Firebase storage.  I have been going around Camera, File, File path, Plugins,etc but not seems to find a valid solution for uploading mp4 file from my gallery to Storage.

I have tried this at first (but it has not worked):

**uploadpage.ts**

```
  async selectVideo(){
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
      // encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA
    }
    let result = await this.camera.getPicture(options);
    result.then((uri) => {
      this.spinner.load();
  this.selectedVideo = uri;
 }, (err) => {
  // Handle error
  this.helper.presentToast(err.message);
 });
  }




  //Upload video
 uploadVideo(){
    if(this.selectedVideo){
      this.spinner.load();
    //upload task 
     let upload= this.api.uploadVideo(this.selectedVideo)
     upload.then().then(res => {
       let otherData={title:this.title,category:this.type, thumbnail:this.thumbnail}
       this.api.storeInfoToDatabase(res.metadata, otherData).then(()=>{
       this.spinner.dismiss();
       })
     })

    }

  }
```

**api.ts**

```
uploadVideo(data): AngularFireUploadTask{
  let newName = `${new Date().getTime()}.mp4`;
  let footballerId = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data')).uid;
   return this.afStorage.ref(`videos/${newName}`).putString(data);
}
storeInfoToDatabase(metaInfo, data){
  let toSave={
    created:metaInfo.timeCreated,
    url: metaInfo.downloadURLs[0],
    fullPath: metaInfo.fullPath,
    contentType: metaInfo.contentType,
    footballerId:'',
    title: data.title || '',
    type:data.type || '',
    thumbnail: data.thumbnail || '',
  }
  toSave.footballerId = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data')).uid;
  return this.addVideo(toSave);
}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Okay! ? do you have any solution to this?